# How can I get current year and at the same time get only past years by a provided param?

Tags: sql-server-2008

For example if you provide 4 as the param it will return the current year and past 4 years:
2013 and (2012, 2011, 1010, 2009)

Comment: how/where are you going to do this?  provide some example code to show usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is a list of years like:

```
years
-----------
2013
2012
2011
2010
2009
```

This query should do it:

```
DECLARE @interval INT
SET @interval = 4
;WITH DateSequence( years ) AS
(
    SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) AS Years
        UNION ALL
    SELECT Years - 1
        FROM DateSequence
        WHERE Years > YEAR(getdate())-@interval
)

--select result
SELECT * FROM DateSequence OPTION (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

Comment: oh man you just answer withouth any intrigue and %@$ questions, you know what I (we) want, thanks a lot bro, blessings.